# How do I get the score to reset

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Once the player dies and starts the game, the score is not resetting and staying as the previous score. I would like the score to reset once the player dies or leaves the game. How do you do this?

```
public class ScoreScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public static int scoreValue = 0;
    Text score;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        score = GetComponent<Text>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        score.text = "Score: " + scoreValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you restart the game are you reloading a scene?

Comment: there is a pause menu that the player can choose to go to the main menu and start the game again. or if they die the game goes back to main menu. However the score stays the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`score.text` is storing the evaluated value of `Score:` and whatever is stored in `scoreValue` at the time `Update()` is called.  None of your code ever updates `scoreValue` from what you've shown.

Also be aware of `scoreValue` being `static`, be sure that accurately reflects your intention (e.g. is `scoreValue` a property of the `ScoreScript` class or each instance of it?).  Note that `score` is not static, and I would expect both of those to have the same behavior (either both static or not).

i.e. something like

```
public class ScoreScript : MonoBehaviour {

public static int scoreValue = 0;
Text score;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    score = GetComponent<Text>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    score.text = "Score: " + scoreValue;
}

void ScoreReset() {
    scoreValue = 0;
}

void AddPoints(int points) {
    scoreValue += points;
}
}
```

Comment: @Eddge fair enough, so I removed those.

Comment: i tried this solution and the score still doesnt reset

Comment: @B.john is something actually calling `ScoreReset()` like an event triggered by the player dying or leaving the game?  Or, have you taken the `static` keyword off of `scoreValue` and reloaded the scene?

Comment: @pmiller3 where would I put the scoreReset()?

Comment: @B.john in whatever conditions you want to trigger it... like wherever the player dies, or leaves the game.  There should be another area of code where you might have events like that... perhaps check out https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/game-over or https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter/player-health

Comment: @pmiller thank you for your help, I just created a new void Awake() scoreValue = 0;

Answer (score -1):

If you load the scene after player die `scoreValue` will be 0 cause as I see that you assign 0 in your above code.

Comment: Can you expand this explanation a bit? Currently, it appears it should be a comment  as you aren't really solving OP's issue but stating it shouldnt do that if they are reloading(Which doesnt solve the issue).  Maybe add a simple example of how to reload the current scene with something like `Scene scene = SceneManager.GetActiveScene(); SceneManager.LoadScene(scene.name);`